# Sprite animation on mouse click

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make sprite animation with 3 images and I need that animation to play on single mouse click.

I tried to use this code, that worked for standing and walking animations, but when I use it for shooting, animation can't happen, because mouse click is fast (It works if I hold mouse button though).

```py
        if self.standing:
            if now - self.last_update > 50:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.game.player_idles)
                self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.game.player_idles[self.current_frame], (64, 55))
                self.image_copy = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the event queue.

In `update`, replace:

```
    if mouse[0]:
        self.shooting = True
        self.standing = False
        self.moving = False
    else:
        self.shooting = False
```

with:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            shoot()
```

You can then get rid of the `shooting` bool altogether, and add the graphics changes made `if self.shooting` to your `shoot` function. Or, if you want to keep the `shooting` bool, you can do something like this:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.shooting = True
            self.moving = False
            self.standing = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            self.shooting = False
```

This code will be more responsive, since it works whenever an event (a click) is inputted by the user, rather than whether the mouse button is being held down.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I [tried to replace](https://imgur.com/a/PlPGP89) what you said, but for some reason nothing is changing. Either self.shoot() or self.shooting = True is not working for me when I press mouse buttons.
(I'm really sorry for possible misunderstanding, I'm using python for about 1-2 weeks)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are calling the animations for the shooting part.

Can you post your code for that? I could probably tell more then. Otherwise my code may not be meaningful/useful. I am sorry for that.
(I cannot comment yet)

Check for mouse click state in the pygame events. If you find a click, store it in a flag(s) like you are doing for the standing part.

We shall use a variable called click_animation_state here to see which frame we are currently in.

```
self.game.shooting_frames = [img1, img2, img3]

if self.mouse_clicked:
    if now - self.last_update > time_threshold:
        self.last_update = now
        self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % 
        len(self.game.shooting_frames)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.game.click_frames[self.current_frame], (64, 55))
        self.image_copy = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
```

Comment: I have [code](https://github.com/vitalezzz98/Game2/blob/Tile-Game-v0.3/Tile-Game/sprites.py) you can check it in Player class / update section. I believe I tried your exact method and it works for me only when I hold mouse button
I should've say it: I want that animation somehow loop through its 3 images and then reset to 0 / other animations, and that's all should be done in a single mouse click.